# Second toolbar like in Mail + Toolbar under a NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstoolbar

I have searched google and SO but i can't seem to find my answer (which is strange)

How do I create a second row in a toolbar like in Xcode and Apple Mail?

[image: Second row toolbare with buttons in Xcode]
[image: Second row toolbare with buttons in Mail]

Second: I really like to be able to make a "toolbar" or button bar underneath a ScrollView or something, like most other applications have. Is it a Custom View or is there an easier way?

[image: button/tool -bar below a ScrollView]

[image: Lower area of SourceList in Apple Mail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are custom components, you will need to either code them yourself or find something that someone else has already created which looks similar to what you want.

Try browsing around [CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/) and similar sites, there are plenty of good-looking classes that you can throw into your app (be careful with the licensing though, it might require attribution)

Comment: Dude.. You just made my day..